# Update Textbox in page (real time)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm edited my question,
I have a submit button and textbox in Default.aspx page. I'm open two window Default.aspx. I want to input text into textbox and press submit in this window, other window will update textbox real time.

Please help me !

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is similar to chat application.
On receiving a value from one client(browser window), you want to send it to another.

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is a good option to keep push data to connected clients.

However if you do want to do it yourself for some reason, the most efficient method to build this in asp.net is to use a [IHttpAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx) and ajax requests.

Here is a [complete working project that implements this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42734/Using-IHttpAsyncHandler-and-XMLHttpRequest-to-push), along with ajax.

Comment: The answer is still the same. If you want to "push" data to another client, you have to have a connection open to it. Using  IHttpAsyncHandler allows you to push data when it is received. Take a look at that sample, you can download and try it. It already implements what you want.